# If a Java app is running as a service how can the Spring context be closed?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, heap-memory

I wrote a java application meant to run as a service which is using Spring for DI.
Since this app is running "forever" it will never get to the point it closes the Spring context.

May this cause issues in long term? For these cases is it maybe better to create objects in standard way rather than injecting them using Spring?

I can also see the heap usage slowly increasing, I am not sure this could be the cause.

Thank you.

Comment: If Spring app is configured as service, that generally means its components are configured as stateless singletons, so spring can continue running as long as it needs to without refreshing anything, since it will not allocate any more components. If your heap usage grows continuously, that usually means problems on your side, not Spring's, just as [galovics suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43320221/7470253)

Comment: How a an app can be configured as a service? Is there any change on the Spring side?

Comment: Not really, this usually only means that your Spring components are stateless services themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem if you don't have memory leaks in your application.

If you see your heap increasing continuously then there might be something which has nothing to do with Spring.

If you don't have any ideas what's causing the memory consumption then I'd suggest to take a look on some JVM tools, for example JVisualVM is one option which is available in the JDK. With this you can easily check what your threads are doing, which objects you have in the memory which are growing.